# View packet data of ping

Tags: networking, ping, packet, icmp

Is there a flag or other utility (perhaps `tcpdump`?) that can be used to see the outgoing packets that are sent via the `ping` utility? For example:

```
$ ping -c 5 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.14.78): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.217.14.78: icmp_seq=0 ttl=53 time=1.244 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.78: icmp_seq=1 ttl=53 time=1.298 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.78: icmp_seq=2 ttl=53 time=1.195 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.78: icmp_seq=3 ttl=53 time=1.283 ms
64 bytes from 172.217.14.78: icmp_seq=4 ttl=53 time=1.322 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.195/1.268/1.322/0.045 ms
```

For example, how can I see those 5 packets that are sent to Google (for example, in hex output)?

Answer (score 3):

First listen with tcpdump :

```
$ sudo tcpdump -c 10 -vvv -XX -i any icmp
```

- -c 10 = Exit after receiving 10 packets (5 requests and 5 replies) = ping -c 5.
- -vvv = Even more verbose output.
- -XX = Print in hex and ASCII.
- -i any = all interfaces
- icmp = Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP)

Next, open a new terminal :

```
$ ping -c 5 google.com
```

Check for "ICMP echo request"